What ratio of acid to milk should I aim for when making a clarified milk punch?
I am attempting to replicate a drink I had while traveling last year. It was an NA, coffee cocktail made by

making cold brew with milk instead of water
curdling the cold brew with some kind of vinegar (I don't remember the specific kind, but I have been using apple cider [5% acidity] and seasoned rice vinegar)
straining out the curds for a clarified coffee drink

I am new to making drinks like this and am having trouble getting the cold brew to clarify. I believe either my ratio of acid to milk is wrong, but that is only a guess. Does anyone with experience making clarified cocktails have any input that can help?
